# How does fdisk utility use CHS addressing on SSDs?

Tags: disk

In my free time I am working on a personal project for reading and writing all kinds of disk structures like MBR, GPT, EXT2/3/4, NTFS, etc. While working on the MBR part I noticed that the `fdisk` utility populates the CHS address fields of the MBR partition entries when formatting a device... even if the target device is an SSD or a normal file like a disk image. The lack of any actual cylinders and heads/platters in an SSD or file made me curious: What does `fdisk` write to those CHS address fields?

Well, after some testing (i.e. formatting a normal file multiple times with different start sectors for the first partition), I am fairly certain that `fdisk` actually writes CHS addresses into those fields. But how does `fdisk` determine the cylinder/head sizes for an SSD or for a normal file? I can't imagine the `HDIO_REQ` and `HDIO_GETGEO` ioctls working on normal files.

Comment: CHS addressing scheme is applicable for Hard disks. I think SSD has either row addressing or (block, page) addressing.  Reference - https://phandinhlan.medium.com/lets-develop-part-2-4276fe266ef9

Comment: CHS for SSD is abstracted. The geometry is often fiddled for counterfeit flash drives. You can still write to data structtures in unpartitioned space. You can still skip with dd to jump to an arbitrary seek location. Where the page is written does not matter. Only where it appears to be.  It is possible for not-so-intelligent or legacy software to not be aware of boundary alignment. But they will still work.

Answer (score 1):

After some more testing (see below) I am confident that the CHS addresses produced by `fdisk` always satisfy `sector % (255 * 63) == 63 * chs.head + (chs.sector - 1)` and `chs.cylinder == 0` with `chs.head` only taking values in [0,254] and `chs.sector` only taking values in [1,63], regardless of the underlying (device) file's size.

I used the following Python script to quickly convert from LBAs to `fdisk`-CHSs to generate test cases. Tested on normal files as well as device files with different sector sizes.

```
import ctypes, subprocess

class chs_struct (ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
    # Unused: No system modern enough to run Python uses CHS addressing
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ( "head",        ctypes.c_uint8    ),
        ( "sector",      ctypes.c_uint8, 6 ),
        ( "cylinder_hi", ctypes.c_uint8, 2 ),
        ( "cylinder_lo", ctypes.c_uint8    )
    ]

def chs_of_sector (first_sector, filename):
    """
    Formats the file pointed to by filename with a new MBR whose first and
    only partition is a primary partition starting at the specified
    first_sector. This function returns the corresponding CHS address the
    fdisk utility calculated.
    """
    
    with subprocess.Popen(
        ["fdisk", filename],
        universal_newlines = True,
        stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout = subprocess.DEVNULL,
        stderr = subprocess.DEVNULL
    ) as proc:
        #                            +------------------------------------------- Create new MBR
        #                            |    +-------------------------------------- Create new partition
        #                            |    |    +--------------------------------- Make it a primary partition...
        #                            |    |    |    +----------------------------   and make it the first partition...
        #                            |    |    |    |            +---------------   starting at this sector
        #                            |    |    |    |            |         +----- Max out partition size
        #                            |    |    |    |            |         |    + Write MBR to file
        #                            v    v    v    v       vvvvvvvvvvvv   v    v
        proc.communicate("\n".join(["o", "n", "p", "1", str(first_sector), "", "w"]))

    with open(filename, "rb") as file:
        file.seek(447) # Offset of the first partition entry's first sector CHS address
        chs = chs_struct.from_buffer_copy(file.read(3))

    return (chs.head, chs.cylinder_hi << 8 + chs.cylinder_lo, chs.sector)
```